# Functional based component marker problem

Tags: reactjs

Hi i am using vanilla map js in react but in this functional based component marker is not showing but in class based component it works. But i want to use it in functional based component. Please help me. In this functional based component i am using react useEfect.

````
const GoogleMap = () => {

    // const [googleMap, setGoogleMap] = useState();
    // const [marker, setMarker] = useState();
    let googleMapRef = React.createRef();
    let map, marker;
    // }
    useEffect(() => {
        const googleMapScript = document.createElement("script");
        googleMapScript.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDEkGijSUn59Urd96tftpKsizYGqkUaMFQ`;
        window.document.body.appendChild(googleMapScript);
        googleMapScript.addEventListener("load", () => {
            map = createGoogleMap();
            marker = createMarker();
        });
    }, [])
    console.log("Marker", marker)


    // componentDidMount() {
    //     const googleMapScript = document.createElement("script");
    //     googleMapScript.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDjjx0ffXrvMyW4V8Y3Wlk-e2c2H2jAcFw`;
    //     window.document.body.appendChild(googleMapScript);
    //     googleMapScript.addEventListener("load", () => {
    //         this.googleMap = this.createGoogleMap();
    //         this.marker = this.createMarker();
    //     });
    // }

    let createGoogleMap = () => {
        new window.google.maps.Map(googleMapRef.current, {
            zoom: 16,
            center: {
                lat: 43.642567,
                lng: -79.387054,
            },
            // disableDefaultUI: true,
        });
    }


    let createMarker = () => {
        const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 43.642567, lng: -79.387054 },
            map: map,
        })
        return marker
    }

    return (
        <div
            id="google-map"
            ref={googleMapRef}
            style={{ height: '75vh', width: "100%" }}
        />
    )

}

export default GoogleMap;```
````

Comment: Google Maps have working examples: